# extract data from Json array in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a webservice url and when i load the url on browser it shows a json array like i mentioned below,

["Apple","Orange","Banana"]

this doesnt have a array name. is it possible to get these strings to a listview. if it is possible how to do that. i have researche a lot. but i couldnt fin an proper answer.

i tried like this.but it shows the entire json array.

```
       try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            Content = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }
```

Comment: `ArrayList<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>(); for (int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) { fruits.add(array.optString(i)); }`

Answer (score 0):

if you get a String from the response, do:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(string);
```

once you have the json array, you can do:

```
array.get(index);
```

to get the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution too after doing a deep research.

```
String string = yourjson;

JSONObject o = new JSONObject(yourjson);
JSONArray a = o.getJSONArray("types");
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
    Log.d("Type", a.getString(i););
}
```